# Getting an InvalidCharacterError when running app through UWP and Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, uwp, invalid-characters

This code is generated through BuckleScript -> JS, I can't see where the invalid character is.

However, I think that this may be an issue where UWP doesn't allow access to the internalhost as a feature, and thus is throwing an error.

I have already added a loop-back exception added the SID and that. I have run CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -is -n=packageFamilyName.

```
function getJidFromUrl(url) {
  var match = url[
  /* path */
  0];

  if (match && !match[1]) {
    var jidString = atob(match[0]); //error line here
    return toJid(jidString);
  }
}
```

> Unhandled exception at line *, column 5 in index.bs.js
>
> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: InvalidCharacterError

Comment: Are you running this code in UWP's WebView or Winjs?
Your parameter `url` is string, you catch the first character names `match`, now your `match` is a char. atob function can't run because this char not encode.
You can try running this code in the browser to see what happened.

Comment: I'm not running with either, just a blank JS Universal Windows app

Comment: So, this issue is a pure javascript issue, it's not specific to UWP. I actually have explained the reason. `Your parameter url is string, you catch the first character names match, now your match is a char. atob function can't run because this char not encode. `

Comment: What I'm getting for the first match[0], is "index.html" not a valid URI, I'm not sure where this is coming from could be the start page you enter in, or the content URI.

Comment: I did not understand why the `match[0]` is 'index.html', it should be a char. Please provide a [mcve] for more diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant to write

```
atob(match);
```

and not

```
atob(match[0]);
```

considering you're doing

```
var match = url[0];
```

Comment: I'm thinking you're sending something to `atob` that it doesn't support. What exactly is `url`, and why are you doing `url[0]`?

Comment: the url is a standard url string like https://blahblah.com/userjid the original function takes in the url, uses reasonreact.router to break down the url into path,search,hash, then uses atob() to get the jidstring.

heres the original function in ReasonReact

```let getJidFromUrl = url => {
  open ReasonReactRouter;
  switch(url.path) {
    | [x] => {
      let jidString = atob(x);
      XMPP.Jid.toJid(Some(jidString));
    }
    | _ => None
  };
};```

I don't know what the buckleScript compiler is doing to be honest.